# How to format an int as an uppercase hex string with 0x prefix?

Tags: python, hex, string-formatting

I have an integer variable:

```
>>> a = id("string")
```

and I want to format `a` to an uppercase hexadecimal string with the prefix `0x`. What's the best way to do this?

These are some incorrect outputs:

```
>>> f"{a:#x}"
'0x115afcae8'

>>> f"{a:#X}"
'0X115AFCAE8'

>>> f"{a:X}"
'115AFCAE8'
```

I *can* get the correct output by just prepending `0x` to the last of those:

```
>>> f"0x{a:X}"
'0x115AFCAE8'
```

but is this really the cleanest way? It sems odd that I couldn't find a way to do this with just the extremely vast [string formatting mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me.

Comment: "incorrect" because either the mantissa comes out lower case or the `0x` comes out upper case?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz What do you mean?

Comment: you seem to reject both the `#` formats (you call them "incorrect") without further comment so I'm asking if I understood you correctly.

Comment: yes, I'd want the `x` in  the `0x` prefix to be lowercase, but the letters in the number to be uppercase: `115AFCAE8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems to be that

```
>>> f"0x{a:X}"
'0x115AFCAE8'
```

is the best way to do this, as this cannot be done with just string formatting.

Comment: With this answer, for negative numbers you get "0x-115A", which is a bit ugly. Putting the minus sign before "0x" wouldn't be better ?